# Hide using ngClick in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, concatenation

I have a table of profils, so to add one i click in a button, then `setAdded()` function show the form.
So what I want is when I select a multiple technologies the specific labels will be shown. I tried this but didn't work.

I have a form like this:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text"
           ng-model="profil.libelleProfil_en" />

    <label>Display</label>
    <input type="checkbox"
           ng-model="profil.displayProfil" />

    <label>Technologie</label>
    <select multiple>
      <option value="{{tecno.idTechnologie}}" 
              ng-repeat="tecno in technologies" 
              ng-click="setClicked({{tecno.idTechnologie}})">
         {{tecno.libelleTechnologie_en}}
      </option>
    </select>

    <div ng-repeat="tecno in technologies">
      <label ng-hide="tecSel{{tecno.idTechnologie}}">
         {{tecno.libelleTechnologie_en}}</label>
      <input ng-model="profil.libelleProfil_en" type="text" 
             ng-hide="tecSel{{tecno.idTechnologie}}" />

      <label ng-hide="tecSel{{tecno.idTechnologie}}">
         {{tecno.libelleTechnologie_en}} Profil Name</label>
      <input ng-model="profil.libelleProfil_en" type="text" 
             ng-hide="tecSel{{tecno.idTechnologie}}" />

    </div>
    <button ng-click="addProfil(profil)">New Profil</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

and in my script i have something like this:

```
$scope.setAdded = function(){               
                $scope.addState = !$scope.addState; 
                $scope.table = [];
                angular.forEach($scope.technologies,function(value,key){
                   var j = value.idTechnologie;
                   $scope.table.push(j);
                   $scope.tecSel +""+ j == true;
               });
            };
```

Comment: what is $scope.tecSel +""+ j == true;

Comment: i use it in a label <label data-ng-hide="tecSel{{tecno.idTechnologie}}"> or in in the input to hide it or show it , so j={{tecno.idTechnologie}} , in normal it should be $scope.tecSel +""+ j = true.

Comment: I think i now what you mean `$scope['tecSel' + j ] = true;` . I don't think it has the same effect that you expect neither the <label data-ng-hide="tecSel{{tecno.idTechnologie}}">

Comment: My other problem, is anyone who can show me how to collect data from the input generated for each technologie selected???